# How to mount an entire shared server? (and not each shared folder separately)

Tags: windows, sharing, cifs, smb

I have a router serving its USB attached drive through SMB.
From a Windows machine, I can mount the root folder of the shared folder.
On Ubuntu, following various guides, I am able to mount the sub-folders one by one, ie:

```
/etc/fstab
//my-server/Music     /media/asus/music     cifs  user,uid=ubuntuuser,credentials=/home/ubuntuuser/.asuscred,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
//my-server/OS        /media/asus/os        cifs  user,uid=ubuntuuser,credentials=/home/ubuntuuser/.asuscred,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
//my-server/Pictures  /media/asus/pictures  cifs  user,uid=ubuntuuser,credentials=/home/ubuntuuser/.asuscred,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
//my-server/Videos    /media/asus/videos    cifs  user,uid=ubuntuuser,credentials=/home/ubuntuuser/.asuscred,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
...
```

That's fine but:

- I get an icon in the left-hand side dock for each mounted share
- If I have another folder on my USB, I need to manually add it to
  `/etc/fstab`

How can I mount just the root somewhere?
I tried:

```
//my-server     /media/asus/root     cifs  user,uid=ubuntuuser,credentials=/home/ubuntuuser/.asuscred,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

Without luck.

Comment: ...and what is the "the root folder of the shared folder" that you can supposedly mount in Windows?

Comment: //my-server directly mapped to whatever drive letter I want (Y:\ for example).